# How can i implement cookies in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I've got a few lists filled with forms like this on my website:

```
    <Input type="checkbox"> Option 1
    <Input type="checkbox"> Option 2
```

And so on

How could i implement cookies with these? So that visitors to my website get their setting saved.

Comment: I dont suggest using cookies as there's no 100% chance that users have cookies enabled. Try using sessions rather, you can try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/ It saves data for logged in and not logged in users but it only saves it for a certain number of hours or so. So it's not persistent. It also saves each users data in the wp_options table on the database.

Comment: Is there a way for example to save these options through member only content?

Comment: also is there a plugin that is more permanent?

Comment: Your probably looking for something like http://www.gravityforms.com/ You can add more fields for users and pass it to the database and it will save for each user and it's permanent. If you don't want to buy Gravity forms licence, then I would suggest doing something like this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9121/saving-custom-data-for-each-user

Comment: how would it save permanently? Would it be in a database or actually viewable, i need these checkboxes to be viewed as either checked or unchecked by the visitor according to what they have and have not checked.